# Problems using POSIXct with ">" and "<" in R

Tags: r, excel, date, time, timezone

I'm getting inconsistent results when trying to subset data based on a date being before or after some POSIXct date and time. When I make a string of dates like this:

```
 myDates <- c(as.POSIXct("2014-12-27 08:10:00 UTC"), 
         as.POSIXct("2014-12-27 08:15:00 UTC"),
         as.POSIXct("2014-12-27 09:30:00 UTC"))
```

and then try to subset to find all the entries in `myDates` that were before 8:15 a.m. on Dec. 27, 2014 like this:

```
 myDates[myDates < as.POSIXct("2014-12-27 08:15:00")]
```

that works fine and I get

```
 "2014-12-27 08:10:00 PST"
```

(although I don't understand why it says "PST" for the time zone; that's where I am, but I set it to UTC).

However, my original date and time data were in Excel, where they were in numeric format. I imported them as a data.frame called Samples and converted the date and time column into POSIXct format by doing:

```
 as.POSIXct(Samples$DateTime, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")
```

Now, I'm having hair-pulling, head-onto-desk-bashing frustrations with subsetting those dates. Take one date in particular, `x <- Samples$DateTime[34]`, which, according to the output R gives me, is `"2014-12-27 08:10:00 UTC"`. If I check whether x < 2014-12-27 08:15, that should be true, and here's what I see:

```
 x < as.POSIXct("2014-12-27 08:15:00 UTC")

 TRUE
```

But x should NOT be less 2014-12-27 8:09:00 UTC, right? This is what I see:

```
 X < as.POSIXct("2014-12-27 08:09:00 UTC")

 TRUE
```

Why, for the love of Pete, does R tell me that 8:10 is *before* 8:09?!? This doesn't seem to be a problem for data that I just type in like above, only for data I've imported from Excel.

Comment: You probably need to get everything in the same timezone first. Try `as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2014-12-27 08:10:00 UTC", tz="UTC"))` vs. `as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2014-12-27 08:10:00 UTC"))` and you will see they are actually numerically different - specify the `tz=` explicitly when importing as the `"UTC"` in your text strings will not be detected.

Comment: Yes!!!! I thought that the problem must be with the Excel data, but you're right! It's the way I'm trying to subset! THANK YOU! Post this as an answer and I'd be happy accept that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to get everything in the same timezone first. Try

```
as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2014-12-27 08:10:00 UTC", tz="UTC"))
#[1] 1419667800
# equivalent to "2014-12-27 08:10:00 UTC"
```

vs.

```
as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2014-12-27 08:10:00 UTC"))
#[1] 1419631800
# equivalent to 8:10 in local timezone - in my case Aust. EST.
# "2014-12-27 08:10:00 AEST"
```

You can see that they are actually numerically different.

To fix this, specify the `tz=` explicitly when importing as the `"UTC"` in your text strings will not be detected on input.

Answer (score 0):

Also, be really careful with variable names. Likely you just slipped in typing it in here, but in the description of the problem and the first logical comparison you used `x` and in the second one you used `X`.

R is case sensitive, so it would not compare your date to the one stored in `x`. If anything else was stored in memory with `X` it may actually be that you were given the right answer for the question you asked.

Comment: Thanks, @bethanyP. Yes, that was just a typo here.